# What's the difference between 'chmod g+s' and 'chmod +s'

Tags: linux, permissions, command, chmod, ping

My user is already in 'wheel' group of CentOS and the 'ping' command doesn't work:

```
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

A guide here about using 'chmod +s' for 'ping':
https://github.com/MichaIng/DietPi/issues/1012#issuecomment-532840857

However, I saw another command 'chmod g+s', how does it differ from 'chmod +s'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chmod +s` sets *both* the UID and GID bits, while `chmod g+s` sets only the GID bit (and `chmod u+s`sets only the UID).

UID and GID bit lets the program *run as* the owner and/or the owner's group - rather than as the user and group of who actually started it.  For example, a program may always run as if it had been started by root.

Lets say you have a file with ownership root:adm...  `chmod g+s`would give the program access to some logs (bad?)...  `chmod +s` would in addition let the program run with full root privileges (much much worse!).